# How to make Json format that updates the values

Tags: ruby, json

I'm kind of new regarding Ruby, however I'm working on a script that pulls data out of a ticketing system list of tickets in the queue, time when it was created and their status and generates a file with the following json structure:

```
{"LastUpdate":1373409010,

    "Service":[

        {"time":"07-09-2013 19:22:02 GMT","region":"","description":"All Systems OK.","service":""},

        {"time":"07-09-2013 11:04:02 GMT","region":"","description":"All Systems OK.","service":""}

    ]

}
```

I already have the script that is pulling the data from its source however I'm having difficulties building this structure.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'highline/import'
require 'pp'


@usersol='user'
@passol='password'
@urlsol= "http://dev-webhelpdesk.corp:8081/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa/ra/Tickets?list=group&page=1&limit=25&username=#{@usersol}&password=#{@passol}"


  def ticket_search                                                #looks for tickets in solarwinds
    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(@urlsol))
    url_output = resp.body
    JSON.parse(url_output)
  end


  def ticket_data(result)                                    #gets data needed from the search
     result.each do | data |
      final = data.values_at('id', 'lastUpdated', 'shortSubject', 'shortDetail')
    end
  end

  def messages_content(looking)                                             #gets content of ticket
    looking.each do | messages |
      ticket = messages.has_key? 'id'
        if ticket
         content = messages.values_at('shortDetail')
        end
        pp content
    end
  end

  def lastupdate_time(last)                            #gets content of lastupdate of the ticket
    last.each do | time_check |
      ticket = time_check.has_key? 'id'
        if ticket
          lastupdate = time_check.values_at('lastUpdated')
        end
      pp lastupdate
    end
  end

  def datastructure(format)
     format.each do |lastup|
       reference = lastup.has_key? 'id'
       if reference
         timeid = lastup.values_at('lastUpdated')
         timeid.each do |lines|
           result = ({time:"#{lines}", region:'', id:'', description:'All Systems OK', service:''})
           puts result
         end
       end
     end
```

So I'm open to any suggestion on how to fix or improve my script, then one of things that I want to know is how can I make this structure, so this script will be deploy by a cronjob every 3 hours, so the LastUpdate line in the structure needs to reflect that time stamp and then the content of Service should be update every time the check happens with the list of tickets in the queue.

Example:

```
# first time that it run it find 2 tickets with the time when they were ack 

{"LastUpdate":1373409010,

    "Service":[

        {"time":"07-09-2013 19:22:02 GMT","region":"","description":"All Systems OK.","service":""},

        {"time":"07-09-2013 11:04:02 GMT","region":"","description":"All Systems OK.","service":""}

    ]

}

# second time that runs and so on

{"LastUpdate":1373409011,

    "Service":[

        {"time":"07-09-2013 19:22:02 GMT","region":"","description":"All Systems OK.","service":""},

        {"time":"07-09-2013 19:22:02 GMT","region":"","description":"All Systems OK.","service":""}

    ]

}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Ruby, but shouldn't you be storing the result of `JSON.parse(url_output)` somewhere?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained in detail how far you've come on your own - exactly what works and what doesn't. And gave us more direct questions - not "please give me general critique".

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good to get into the object oriented thinking of ruby. So I would recommend a skeleton like this (I kept all of your imports although some of them seem unnecessary):

```ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'highline/import'
require 'pp'


USERNAME  = 'user'
PASSWORD  = 'password'
URL       = "http://dev-webhelpdesk.corp:8081/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa/ra/Tickets?list=group&page=1&limit=25&username=#{USERNAME}&password=#{PASSWORD}"
PATH      = 'myfile.txt'

class DataFetcher
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def ticket_data
    parse_data(perform_search)
  end

  # Parses the data from JSON
  def parse_data(data)
    # code goes here
  end

  # Do the HTTP-request
  def perform_search
    #code goes here
  end
end

class DataWriter
  def initialize(ticket_data)
    @ticket_data = ticket_data
  end

  def write_to(path)
    File.write(path, construct_data)
  end

  def construct_data
    dump_json(construct_hash)
  end

  def dump_json(data)
    JSON.pretty_generate(data)
  end

  # Construct the hash that will be turned into JSON,
  # we assume that the DataFetcher has properly formatted it
  def construct_hash
    output = {
      "LastOutput" => Time.now.to_i,
      "Service" => @ticket_data
    }
  end

end

# This is where we actually do the work:
data    = DataFetcher.new(URL)
writer  = DataWriter.new(data)
writer.write_to(PATH)
```

You still need to hook up stuff to make the script run as a cron job. I would also add timestamps to the filenames, unless you intend the script to always overwrite the file.